TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') in Angular RxJS subscription
I'm encountering a TypeError in my Angular component with RxJS observables. The error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" is pointing to my usage of filter on an array.
The error specifically happens within the userService.users$ subscription when attempting to filter this.users. The intention is to exclude the logged-in user from the list.
What should I do differently?
Here is a simplified version of the relevant code:
user-list.component.ts
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  protected readonly Object = Object;
  users!: User[];
  usersSubscription!: Subscription;
  loggedUser!: User;
  loggedUserSubscription!: Subscription;
  groupedAndSortedUsers!: { [key: string]: User[] };

  constructor(public userService:UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.loggedUserSubscription = this.userService.loggedUser$.subscribe(user => {
      this.loggedUser = user;
    })

    this.userService.users$.subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users.filter(user => user?.id !== this.loggedUser.id);
        // Remove the current logged-in user
        const filteredUsers = this.users.filter(user => user?.id !== this.loggedUser.id);
        this.groupedAndSortedUsers = this.userService.groupAndSortUsers(filteredUsers);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.usersSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.loggedUserSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

user.service.ts
export class UserService {
  private _users$: BehaviorSubject<User[] | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<User[] | undefined>(undefined);
  private _loggedUser$: BehaviorSubject<User | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<User | undefined>(undefined);

  constructor(private userHttpService: UserHttpService, private router: Router, private dtoMapperService: DtoMapperService, private matSnackBar: MatSnackBar,) {
    this.fetchUsers();
    this.fetchLoggedUser();
  }

  public get users$(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this._users$.asObservable() as Observable<User[]>;
  }

  public get users(): User[] {
    return this._users$.getValue() as User[];
  }

  public get loggedUser$(): Observable<User> {
    return this._loggedUser$.asObservable() as Observable<User>;
  }

  public get loggedUser(): User {
    return this._loggedUser$.getValue() as User;
  }

  public set users(users: User[]) {
    this._users$.next(users);
  }

  public set loggedUser(user: User) {
    this._loggedUser$.next(user);
  }

  public fetchUsers() {
    this.userHttpService.fetchUsers().subscribe({
      next: (usersDtos: UserDto[]) => {
        const users = usersDtos.map(userDto => this.dtoMapperService.mapUserDtoToUser(userDto));
        this._users$.next(users);
      }
    });
  }

  public fetchLoggedUser() {
    this.userHttpService.fetchLoggedUser().subscribe({
      next: (userDto: UserDto) => {
        this._loggedUser$.next(this.dtoMapperService.mapUserDtoToUser(userDto))
      }
    })
  }

  public groupAndSortUsers(users: User[]): { [key: string]: User[] } {
    const sortedUsers: { [key: string]: User[] } = {};

    users.forEach(user => {
      const firstLetter = user.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      if (!sortedUsers[firstLetter]) {
        sortedUsers[firstLetter] = [];
      }
      sortedUsers[firstLetter].push(user);
    });

    const sortedKeys = Object.keys(sortedUsers).sort();

    sortedKeys.forEach(letter => {
      sortedUsers[letter].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    });

    const sortedUsersResult: { [key: string]: User[] } = {};
    sortedKeys.forEach(letter => {
      sortedUsersResult[letter] = sortedUsers[letter];
    });

    return sortedUsersResult;
  }
}

user-list.component.ts
<div class="user-list-box">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem">ME</mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <app-user [user]="userService.loggedUser"></app-user>
    
    <mat-list role="list">
      @for (letter of Object.keys(groupedAndSortedUsers); track letter) {
        <mat-list-item role="listitem">{{ letter }}</mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        @for (user of groupedAndSortedUsers[letter]; track user.id) {
          <app-user [user]="user"></app-user>
        }
     }
    </mat-list>
</div>


Does this answer your question? Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

What is the purpose of "as" keyword in this line of code (and other lines also, honestly) return this._users$.asObservable() as Observable<User[]>; having private _users$: BehaviorSubject<User[] | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<User[] | undefined>(undefined);? You subscribed to this observable and got it's initial value, undefined, because the async operation inside class constructor did not load and set new value yet, and got the runtime error. Use "as" keyword carefully, it can cause very nasty runtime bugs that could be seen at compile time otherwise.

@SergeySosunov I get the error Type 'Observable<User | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable' in get loggedUser$() if I remove the as Observable. How should I do it different?

@coder Well that is the point, your Observable is in fact  'Observable<User | undefined>', not the Observable, because initial value of your behaviorSubject is "undefined". Your loggedUser() is in fact also not a : User, it is : User | undefined, and you will get undefined from it if you call this method before constructor async operation is done.

@SergeySosunov so is it better to define loggedUser as User and initialize it as undefined?

You can use the switchMap operator from RxJS to ensure that you have the loggedUser before you subscribe to users$. The switchMap operator maps each value to an Observable, then it flattens all of these inner Observables using switch.
Here’s how you can modify your ngOnInit method:
ngOnInit() {
  this.loggedUserSubscription = this.userService.loggedUser$.pipe(
    switchMap((loggedUser) => { // <-- Add this line
      this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
      return this.userService.users$;
    })
  ).subscribe(users => { <-- only when loggedUser is not null or undefined
    this.users = users.filter(user => user?.id !== this.loggedUser.id);
    const filteredUsers = this.users.filter(user => user?.id !== this.loggedUser.id);
    this.groupedAndSortedUsers = this.userService.groupAndSortUsers(filteredUsers);
  });
}


You need check if users is an array in subscribe function
e.g. you can use (users || []), so if users are "undefined" get the value of an empty array.
this.userService.users$.subscribe((users:any[]) => {
   //you can check the value of users
   console.log(users)
   this.users = (users || []).filter(user => user?.id !== this.loggedUser.id);
   ...
})

